# Google Analytics universal - enhanced ecommerce checkout

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, checkout, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a webshop checkout with 4 steps(urls/pages) on [bodylux.dk](http://bodylux.dk)

1. Basket
2. Adress, payment, shipping details ( it is this page I have questions about)
3. Creditcard/payment gateway
4. Thank you page

The checkout is tracked with the enhanced ecommerce and working.

But I would like to get more fine grained tracking on step 2, this page contains adress fields, payment options and shipping options. And it is on this page most of the users abandon the checkout. I would like to track if the user has entered address, selected shipping, selected payment aso.

But when looking in the documentation for checkout in enhanced ecommerce [enhanced ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) they write only a single sentence about single page checkouts "If you have a single step checkout process or if you have not configured a checkout-funnel in Ecommerce Settings then the step field is optional."

But it is not apparent to me if I should track as an action without a step to track the extra information or if I should use event tracking.

Any hint are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With Enhanced Ecommerce, checkout steps don't have to be necessarily pages, but can be events.

In you case, you can fire events with extra checkout steps when the users completes (correctly) the address fields, payments options and shipping options.
Say you shipping option is a radio button, you could place a javascript event on the selection of this radio button, updating the dataLayer if you have GTM:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'checkout',
  'ecommerce': {
    'checkout': {
      'actionField': {'step': 1}
    }
  }
});
```

And creating a GA tag on GTM, triggering on the 'checkout' event, with EEC enabled using the dataLayer.

Or the EC action and event if you are hardcoding:

```
ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
  'step': 1, 
});
ga('send', 'event', 'Ecommerce', 'checkout');
```